# Adding a named vector to a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, lapply

I have a list of 3 vectors named `AA`, `BB`, and `CC`. I want to add a new named element called `H` to each of these 3 vectors which will show as `H = some number`.

Here is what I have tried with no success:

```
L <- list(AA = c(K = 2225, M = 39911), BB = c(K = 5456, M = 65533), CC = c(K = 15274, M = 48877))

L[[1]]$H <- H = 25
L[[2]]$H <- H = 23
L[[3]]$H <- H = 41
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to accomplish this.  Use, the vector as one of the arguments to `Map` along with the already existing `list` ('L') - assuming that the `length` of the `list` and the `vector` are the same and concatenate (`c`)

```
Map(c, L, H = c(25, 23, 41))
#$AA
#    K     M     H 
# 2225 39911    25 

#$BB
#    K     M     H 
# 5456 65533    23 

#$CC
#    K     M     H 
#15274 48877    41
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
v1 <- c(25, 23, 41)
for(i in seq_along(L)) L[[i]] <- c(L[[i]], H = v1[i])
```

---

Or using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(L, c(25, 23, 41), ~ c(.x, H = .y))
```

Comment: Awesome upvoted just waiting to be able to accept in 5 or so mins.